# Android: Load an HTML page and then load another after few seconds

Tags: android, html, multithreading, webview

I am building a hybrid application (HTML for UI and native code for backend operations). I am using the following code:

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

to load a html page in the application. My question: Is there a way to make this page appear only for few seconds (say 2 seconds) and then load another?

I tried the thread way of making the application sleep:

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
        try {
            thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But, this only makes the UI go blank and finally load the second url.

I know of async task handlers, but, should I use that to handle this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well. Try my answer below.

Comment: @flx: Sure.. Am trying it now.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is using the `Timer`/`TimerTask` for the update.

Use `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(/* Your TimerTask reloading the url */, 0, 2000)` or something similar.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: I tried it.. But, the Timer Task is getting repeated. I dont want it to repeat.. Any suggestion?